# Syntax error while calling a REST webservice

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, rest

I am trying to call a REST web service from JavaScript using jQuery ajax and alert the response. Here is the HTML/JavaScript code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <script>
     $.ajax({ 
             type: "GET",
             dataType: "jsonp",
             url: "https://api.xyz.com/getItem/1013",
             success: function(data){        
                alert(data);
             }
         });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tested the API using CURL and browser, it is working fine. The response is as follows.

```
{
  "endDate": "2017-04-27 10:03:17", 
  "startDate": "2017-03-28 10:03:17", 
  "status": "active"
}
```

When I am opening this page, I am getting the following error in the console.

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

The browser points to the second line as error. I am not able to figure out if there is an issue with the API or client code. I tried in Firefox and Chrome browsers.

Note: I set the `dataType` attribute in the ajax request as `jsonp`, because I am using `api.xyz.com` from `app.xyz.com` which is a cross origin request. If I specify it as `json`, I am getting another error.

Comment: A correct JSONP response would be `callback({
  "endDate": "2017-04-27 10:03:17", 
  "startDate": "2017-03-28 10:03:17", 
  "status": "active"
})`

Comment: Your response isn't JSONP, it's JSON. They aren't directly interchangeable. I'm assuming you've changed the response type to try and get around the 'No Access Control header' warning, right?

Comment: mplungjan, sorry I did not get what you are trying to say. Do you think I should correct the success function call back? if it is, how can I do it?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Yes, I tried to get around 'No Access Control header' warning and changed the dataType to jsonp. If this is not the right way, what would be the correct way?

Comment: Unless you control the server you're calling to be able to add the CORS headers, there's no workaround for the JS code. You will not be able to call that endpoint using JS alone. You'll need to make the call server side instead

Comment: So do I need to make my api server (api.xyz.com/getItem/123) to accept cross origin requests? Yes I control the api.xyz.com server, it is built in Python Flask frame work and deployed on Apache using wsgi.

Comment: Either that OR serve the page with the script from the same server and have `url: "/getItem/1013",`

Comment: Thank you, I have added the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://app.xyz.com' headers in the API response and changed the data type to json, it started working.